# How can I query the Stack Overflow database?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, stack-exchange, data-explorer, database

Some time ago I saw someone had queried their country's users of Stack Overflow in a sub-site of Stack Exchange (if I'm not wrong). I want to know how I can query Stack Overflow's database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) for that. Choose the site of your interest and query away.